# Сочетание "писатель писал"

Tags: лексика

Есть ли нарушение лексической нормы в "**писатель писал**" ?
Учительница сказала, что такое употребление вполне допустимо. 
А вот в сочетании "масло масляное" никаких сомнений не возникает.

*И даже после того, когда писатель, казалось, нашел уже новые слова, «одеяние стиля» для своего поэтического замысла, и тогда он не успокаивается. Начинаются опять поиски за формой, «муки слова». Оттого всю жизнь **писатель пишет** одну каигу, как говорит Флобер, — что не может никак выразить свой основной образ мира, неотступно преследующий его( Э. Лунин. Литературная энциклопедия).*

Answer (score 2):

Не всякое употребление однокоренных слов тавтология. Когада значения порядком разошлись - точно не тавтология. Ну и еще несколько случаев назвать можно, с ними проще на примерах разобраться. 
Вот как в нашем примере. "Сеятель сеет" - еще можно признать за тавтологию, хотя и с оговорками. Но тут сеятель становится таковым только когда сеет. 
Писатель же совершенно не обязательно должен писать в данный момент, чтобы оставться писателем. Да и писать могут не только писатели. Так что конструкция вполне уместна.

Кстати, и не каждая тавтология - зло, которое надлежит искоренять. Но это уже другой разговор.

Answer (score 1):

это уже устоявшиеся сочетания со стертой тавтологичностью. Вполне допустимы. Да и что еще делают читатели? Читают. Строители строят. Учителя учат.

Comment: Понятно, что это не грубая ошибка и что говорить так вполне допустимо, но нежелательно.

Comment: А как по-другому?

Answer (score 0):

Да, это тавтология, так как корни у этих слов одинаковые.   
Многие писатели делают ошибки, некоторые - специально, некоторые - случайно. Возможно, автор слов, цитируемый вами,  не подобрал лучшего сочетания, чем "писатель пишет". К тому же здесь немного разные корни, хотя тавтология остается.

Comment: Я понимаю. Но почему нет нарушения в сочетании "читатели читают","смотрители смотрят"?

Comment: Почему нет? Есть. Довольно неграмотно так говорить.